# C# Com events not firing

Tags: c#, multithreading, events, com

I have a problem and don't know where it is...
if I do this in a windows Form application:

```
private void btnListen_Click(...)
{
    var t = new Thread(DoWork);
    t.SetAppartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    t.Start();
}

the DoWork method...
private void DoWork()
{
    var controls = GetControls();
    foreach (var c in controls)
    {
        control.OnEvent += HandleEvent;
    }
}

private void HandleEvent()
{
    DoSomething...
}
```

The controls are Wrapped Com objects registered with regsrv32

When firing events on controls, I don't recive events in my Windows forms application HandleEvent method.

but if I change the code to this:

```
private void btnListen_Click(...)
{
    DoWork();
}
```

the it works all ok.
I need this to be executed in another thread.

Why isn't this working when using threads?
Please help.

thanks

EDIT:
I also tried this in a windows service. 
Like this:

```
OnStart()
{
    Task t = new Task(()=>DoWork);
    t.Start();
}
```

every thing else is the same and still does not work. And there is no UI thread here.

Comment: Might be that you depend on the windows message pump, which is GUI thread only, in order for the event notification to run.

Comment: Calling Application.Run() is required in an STA thread.  Append it to DoWork().  Several other ways this won't work correctly, the COM server must be created on that same thread.

Comment: I have explicitly set Apartment mode to STA in the new thread. This is the same as setting [STATHREAD] attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was the control driver (COM) dll that didn't work. Installed new version and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a thread in HandleEvent that does what you need it to do. You have to synchronize any thread you create with the UI thread if you need it to interact with the UI.

Comment: So you mean creating another thread in Handle event method? I don't do anything with the ui, just start the event listening.